# Sound card doesn't support format requested using signalgen

Tags: sound

I want to generate a PWM signal on Ubuntu. My first try was to use `siggen` package. Upon launching `signalgen` I have the following error:

```
$ signalgen -v sin 120
signalgen  Ver. 2.3.10 (May 2008)   Digital Signal Generator
/dev/dsp : DAC Opened for output
22050 mono, signed 16 bit, little endian, samples/sec.
8192 bytes per DAC buffer.
[signalgen] Invalid argument : Sound card doesn't support format requested.
$ sudo signalgen -v sin 120
signalgen  Ver. 2.3.10 (May 2008)   Digital Signal Generator
[signalgen] Input/output error : /dev/dsp
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last Ubuntu release with `/dev/dsp` support was 10.04. After that support for `/dev/dsp` was removed.

To still be able to use older software that rely on `/dev/dsp` there is a compatibility wrapper [padsp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/padsp.1.html) which redirects sound output meant for `dsp` to a running pulseaudio server. We may use this wrapper with the following terminology:

```
padsp [options] APPLICATION [arguments ...]
padsp signalgen -v sin 120
```

By this we may be able to also play the output of **signalgen** to our soundcard. The OSS complatibility layer will be installed as a dependency with [siggen](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/siggen) [image: Install siggen].

If we do not want to output the sound directly we can use `signalgen` to directly write a raw audio file to then play this file through ALSA using `aplay`

```
signalgen -w filename -t 5 sin 120 & aplay filename
```

Note that signalgen will exit if `filename` already existed.

---

A better approach to generate waves without the need of a compatibility layer would be applications that are able to directly address ALSA or PuleAudio.

#### [Sox](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sox) [image: Install sox].

Sox will install the command line utility **[play](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/sox.1.html)** which will not only play sound files but can also generate audio waveforms and can add effects to them:

```
play -n synth sine 120.0 gain 0.0
```